# When to use 'angeboten' and when to use 'bot'?

Tags: verb, verb-usage, tense, separable-verb

When the following sentence (in English) is translated to German:

> The man offered the actor the car.

It becomes:

> Der Mann bot dem Schauspieler das Auto an.

"Offered" in German is "angeboten". Yet, in the previous sentence, it is "bot".

Why is this the case? When should *"angeboten"* be used, and when should *"bot"* be used?

Comment: I would like to add that angeboten is a "Partizip zwei" for anbeiten, You would start it with lowercase "a". The related noun would be "Angebot" (with uppercase "A")

Comment: it's not "bot". it's "bot an". that "an" is part of the verb.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The verb is, in its infinitive form (the form you need to look it up in a dictionary):

> to offer = *anbieten*

Like in

> I want to offer you a drink.
> Ich möchte dir ein Getränk **anbieten.**

The form for *Perfekt*, as you correctly found out, is:

> angeboten
>
> I did offer you a drink.
> Ich habe dir ein Getränk **angeboten.**

But this verb is a separable verb. It has a prefix (*an∙*) that in many situations has to be detached from the main part of the verb and moved to the end of the sentence. This is the case in Präteritum, which is another form of past tense. Here we have:

> bot an
>
> I offered you a drink.
> Ich **bot** dir ein Getränk **an.**

- For details see [Separable verbs on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb)
- There are also [more than 200 Questions on German.Stackexchange dealing with separable verbs](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=separable%20verb)

Comment: `I did offer you a drink.` Shouldn't that be `I have offered you a drink`?

Comment: @JAD German _Perfekt_ and _Präteritum_ don't correspond to English _present perfect_ and _past simple_. (In meaning, that is.) That said, it should probably either be `I have offered you a drink` or `I offered you a drink`.

Comment: A small addition from a native speaker: "bot" will seldom be used in informal conversation between younger people. It sounds a little too formal for everyday talk.

Answer (score 7):

That "offered" means "angeboten" is only half of the truth.

"Offered" in English can be the perfect participle, or it can be past tense.

The perfect participle of "anbieten" (to offer) is "angeboten":

> He has offered the car.
> Er hat das Auto angeboten.

But the translation of "offered" when it means past tense is different and depends on number and person:

> I offered
> Ich bot an
>
> You (familiar) offered
> Du botest an
>
> You (polite) offered
> Sie boten an
>
> He/She/It offered
> Er/Sie/Es bot an
>
> We offered
> Wir boten an
>
> You (guys) offered
> Ihr botet an
>
> They offered
> Sie boten an

Comment: Finally, *They offered* is identical to *You (polite) offered*.

Answer (score 6):

Your example uses the simple past (*Präteritum*). You could rewrite it using the present perfect (*Perfekt*)

> Der Mann hat dem Schauspieler das Auto angeboten

The *Perfekt* is used more often in speech and the *Präteritum* more often in writing

The verb *anbieten* is a [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb) verb